# Cardinality of double cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, cardinals

We show that the sets of double cosets $K\backslash G/H$ is in bijection with $K\backslash(G/H)$. So $\vert K\backslash(G/H) \vert = \vert G/H \vert /\vert K \vert = (\vert G \vert / \vert H \vert)/\vert K \vert$. But for the example $S_2\backslash S_3/S_2=\{\{Id,(12)\},\{(132),(13),(123),(23)\}\}$, $ S_2 \backslash S_3 /S_2$ is of cardinality 2 but $(\vert S_3 \vert / \vert S_2 \vert)/\vert S_2 \vert=1.5$

Comment: Why is the cardinality different if there is a bijection?

Comment: What is the second object $K\setminus(G/H)$? And why does it have cardinality $|G/H|/|K|$?

Comment: $G/H$ is the quotient of $G$ by $H$ and it has cardinality $\vert G \vert /\vert H \vert$. So $K\backslash(G/H)$ is the quotient of $G/H$ by $K$ and so we get $(\vert G \vert/\vert H \vert )/\vert K \vert$ no?

Comment: No.  The left action of $K$ on the set $G/H$ is not fixed-point-free.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Oh, I see what you mean $K\backslash (G/H)$ is not a quotient by $K$ but rather the set of orbits of the action of $K$ on $G/H$, even though I don't understand why one would call it like that

Answer (score 1):

The left action of $K$ on $G/H$ is not related to double cosets. For example if $K\subseteq H$ then all orbits of that action are singltons. So there is no bijection between $K\backslash G/H$ and $K\backslash (G/H)$ in general.

Comment: is it correct that $K\backslash (G/H)$ is a notation for the set of orbits of the action of $K$ on $G/H$? In general is $G\backslash X$ a notation for the set of orbits for the action? That seems like a weird notation

Comment: Oh, I thought $KgH\mapsto K(gH)$ an bijection?

Comment: Between the set of double cosets for $(H,K)$ and $K\backslash (G/H)$

Comment: No it is almost never a bijection.

Comment: In the example you mention, $K\subset H$, then $orb(gH)=\{k(gH) :  k\in K\}=\{kgH : k\in K\}$, why is this a singleton?